# How to Create Custom Events for Python Asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, mesos, marathon

The Mesos scheduler [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/) has an asynchronous HTTP API. E.g. when one deploys an app by posting a JSON to `/v2/apps` a deployment id is returned. The id can then be used to either poll the deployment state in `/v2/deployments` or by subscribing to `/v2/events` and look for the `deployment_success` event.

I would like to create an asynchronous Python client with coroutines. E.g. `client.deploy_app(...)` should return once the `deployment_success` event arrived but not block.

How can I implement these methods with asyncio? How can I create an event listener? It feels an event loop is made for this but I don't see how I register events.

Answer (score 2):

Creating asynchronous post http requests that needed for `/v2/apps` can be done with `aiohttp` module:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def post(url, json):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, json=json) as resp:
            return await resp.json()


async def main():
    res = await post('http://httpbin.org/post', {'test': 'object'})
    print(res['json'])  # {'test': 'object'}


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

If you want to use `/v2/events` to track deployment success you should request for stream (see api [doc](http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/api-console/index.html)). It can be achieved in `aiohttp` with it's [asynchronous iteration](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html#asynchronous-iteration-support): you just asynchronously read content line-by-line waiting for event you need, for example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def stream(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            async for line in resp.content:
                yield line


async def main():
    async for line in stream('http://httpbin.org/stream/10'):
        print(line)  # check if line contains event you need


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

If you want to use `/v2/deployments` you should request it periodically waiting some delay using `asyncio.sleep`. In this case your function won't be blocking:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.json()


async def main():
    while True:       
        # Make request to see if deplayment finished:
        res = await get('http://httpbin.org/get')
        print(res['origin'])  # break if ok here
        # Async wait before next try:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm afraid I did not express my question clear enough. I'd like to know whether there is another way than   
  
`async def deploy(app):  
    deployment_id = await post(app)  
    await deployment_event(deployment_id)`  
  
which has a race condition anyways.